# CSS File Mod for changing "Shop By" SideBar Text Color not taking effect ?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to change the Font Colour & Style of the Shop By SideBar headings - see attachment.

[http://postimg.org/image/iovzfae1n/][1]

**Code below is'nt working :**

```
.block-layered-nav dt {   border-bottom: 1px solid #D5D5D5;    font-weight: normal;    padding: 0 7px 10px 0; text-transform:capitalize; font-size:14px; 
color:#3d5d76; }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share website url?

Comment: www.isurfke.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit the css file `skin/frontend/default/MAG090172/css/styles.css` and on line 2145 you will find the class you mentioned, update the font color and style and use `!important` for the property not working. Refresh Cache if required.

Comment: MTM - not working even after clearing all caches.  is it showing on your end www.isurfke.com ??  New code: <<.block-layered-nav dt {border-bottom: 1px solid #D5D5D5; font-size:14px; font-weight: normal;  padding: 0 7px 10px 0; text-transform:capitalize; color: #FA0D1D } >>

Comment: how do i use TAG `!important`in the code ?

Comment: like  color: #FA0D1D !important;

Comment: i still see the old one, did you updated the css file i mentioned above. and re-uploaded it?

Comment: i modified the NEW one.  Do i update the OLD CSS ?  But file permission on OLD is 644 ?!

Comment: If you can't update the existing css file, then add the same class in new css file and use the !important like i suggested, hope it will work

Comment: OK - finally its working !! I updated the OLD CSS.  However, i want to put a background colour with White Font Colour.  What is code to do that ?  See attachment link http://postimg.org/image/kihl7k5np/.  Want same style as "Categories"

Comment: use `background-color: #3d5d76;` it will show the color.

Comment: SUPER.  Works like a charm !!